# Autofilter Array, does not show the right values

Tags: vba

I am trying to use Autofilter in VBA but when i try to use the below code it does not show the filtered values, it only shows blanks. When i manually write the array the autofilter works.

```
Dim Filtersheet As Worksheet
Set Filtersheet = Worksheets("Filtersheet")
Dim str As String
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim d As Long


Lastrow = Filtersheet.Cells(Filtersheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With UserFormFilter
If .CheckBoxXX20.Value = True Then str = Chr(34) & "XX20" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxY12.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "Y12" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxZ1212.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "Z12/12" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxXX10.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "XX10" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxV12.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "V12" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxZ2015.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "Z20/15" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxXX1010.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "XX10/10" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxY20.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "Y20" & Chr(34) & ","
If .CheckBoxZ2012Y20.Value = True Then str = str & Chr(34) & "Z20/12 & Y20" & Chr(34) & ","
End With

str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)


Filtersheet.Range("A1", "t" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=10, _ Criteria1:=Array(str), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a (comma-separated) string with the filter values you want to see and pass it to the Autofilter. You are using the `Array`-operator on that string, however, the `Array`-operator sees only one value (the content of `str`) and converts it to an array that holds only one element. So you are filtering for example for a string `"XX20","Y12"` - which results in an empty table.

What you need is an array that has one entry for every value of your list. Instead of using `Array`, you could use the `Split`-command which splits a string into pieces. No need for the quote-character as we are already dealing with strings.

```
str = ""
With UserFormFilter
    If .CheckBoxXX20.Value Then str = str & "XX20" & ","
    If .CheckBoxY12.Value Then str = str & "Y12" & ","
    (...)
End With
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
Filtersheet.Range("A1", "t" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=10, _ 
     Criteria1:=split(str, ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```